# Disqus Plugin Explanation of Dynamic Tags

Tags: dynamic, comments, toolbar, facebook-like, disqus

So I am using the `Disqus Plugin v2.65`. I am trying to edit the `dsq-global-toolbar` at the top of the Disqus comments.

The following tags are in `disqus-comment-system/comments.php`

```
<div id="disqus_thread">

 <?php if (!get_option('disqus_disable_ssr')): ?>
  <?php
   // if (is_file(TEMPLATEPATH . '/comments.php')) {
   // include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/comments.php');
   // }
  ?>
  <div id="dsq-content">
   <ul id="dsq-comments">
```

however on my site there are mulitple tags (the disqus-global-toolbar div) that seem to be dynamically appended between the `dsq-content div` and the `dsq-comments ul`. Where is this coming from and where can I edit this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is coming somewhere around line 3140 in disqus.js

You can use this code to wait for the document to finish loading completely then do your changes (client side):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   window.disqus_no_style = true;

   $.getScript('http://sitename.disqus.com/embed.js', function() {
     var loader = setInterval(function() {
       if($('#disqus_thread').html().length) {
         clearInterval(loader);
         disqusReady();
       }
     }, 1000);
});

 function disqusReady() {
 //whatever you can imagine
 }
});
```

window.diqus_no_style can be deleted as well as the $.getsript wrapper.

Is that what you are looking for?

---

Something like this (use livequery instead of live):

```
 function disqusReady() {
  $('#dsq-global-toolbar').livequery(function() {
    //$(this) will refer to object   
  });
 }
```

Comment: what is the path to the disqus.js file?  Well i was specifically wondering where the  disqus-global-toolbar div gets dynamically loaded so that i could directly make changes to it before it loads.

Comment: That is impossible as far as I know. You cannot interact with the script on the page. Using JQuery, or possibly plain javascript, you can hook the change to the DOM and modify the div. That should be the same end result.

Comment: Ah, I don't know the path to disqus.js. What I did was inspect an element on the page (right click -> last item is Inspect Element) the page, look through the scripts and found disqus.js. I just copy and pasted it out of the browser into a new file.

Comment: Edited answer for jquery's .livequery

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what plug-in you're talking about, but if it's WordPress, I've done the same thing. Modify wp-content/plug-ins/disqus-comment-system/comments.php by adding an event handler for 'afterRender' (fires when the content ready in the DOM, but still hidden), eg. around line 70:

```
config.callbacks.afterRender.push(myFunctionToModifyDisqusOutput);
```